# Browser Scroll bar Has Completely Become White. Not able to change via CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser

Specifically in Chrome when I open a **post** in my [site](http://stylict.com), the browser scroll bar becomes completely white resulting in bad UX.

I tried to change the CSS property by adding the following:

```
scrollbar-face-color: 
scrollbar-shadow-color: 
scrollbar-highlight-color: 
scrollbar-3dlight-color: 
scrollbar-darkshadow-color: 
scrollbar-track-color: 
scrollbar-arrow-color:
```

But, there is no change? Can anyone guide me?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mvce]*

Comment: 1. The desired behavior is default scroll bar in chrome. 2. I've given the website link in the question itself. Issue can be reproduced if you click on a post and check out the scroll bar in Chrome browser

Comment: *I've given the website link in the question* I know, that's why I quoted the close reason stating the code itself must be in your question. This question won't help anybody once you get your issue fixed and the error no longer exists on your site. The minimum amount of code to reproduce it needs to be here if it's going to be useful to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

`::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 3px;}`
`::-webkit-scrollbar-track {-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}`
`::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background: rgba(0,136,204,0.8);-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}`
`::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {background: rgba(0,136,204,0.4);}`

Try like this

Comment: It is changing the scroll bar in my index page. But the issue persists when I open a post.

Comment: try to include the css file in every html file

Comment: It is a wordpress theme. So I had incorporated the change in the common css file.